# Grid concept in Selenium

Tags: selenium-grid

I have written coding for browser opening with grid concept. I wrote the following code. I need to know its correct or wrong.

```
properties
----------
HUB=localhost
PORT=4444
Browser = chrome
Url=http://demo.guru99.com/v4/index.php

Code
----
package processor;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class Browser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        RemoteWebDriver driver;
        Properties prop;
        prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("./config.properties"));

        String hub = prop.getProperty("HUB");
        String port = prop.getProperty("PORT");
        String browser = prop.getProperty("Browser");
        String url = prop.getProperty("Url");


        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome") || browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")
                || browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {



            if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
                try {
                    DesiredCapabilities dc;
                    dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
                    dc.setBrowserName(browser);
                    dc.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
                    driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    System.out.println("Chrome Browser is Initialising..........");
                    driver.manage().window().maximize();
                    driver.get(url);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Problem Occurred while Initialising Chrome Browser. Check for the Driver Name & Path !!!!!!!!!!");
                }
            }

            if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) {
                try {
                    DesiredCapabilities dc;
                    dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
                    dc.setBrowserName(browser);
                    dc.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "./Drivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
                    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                    System.out.println("Internet Explorer is Initialising..........");
                    driver.manage().window().maximize();
                    driver.get(url);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Problem Occurred while Initialising Internet Explorer. Check for the Driver Name & Path !!!!!!!!!!");
                }
            }

            if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
                try {
                    DesiredCapabilities dc;
                    dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
                    dc.setBrowserName(browser);
                    dc.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    System.out.println("Firefox is Initialising..........");
                    driver.manage().window().maximize();
                    driver.get(url);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Problem Occurred while Initialising Firefox. Check for the Driver Name & Path !!!!!!!!!!");
                }
            }
        } 

        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Browser. Check Browser Name in Properties File.......... ");
        }       
    }
}
```

Kindly see the code and tell me the correct code. Grid Concept i need to apply.

Comment: Friends I am stuck with this kindly help me

Comment: Hi Remcow, first thanks for reviewing my code. I ran the script its working perfect. But i learnt that Port no 4444 should be standard. If i change 4443 also its running. That i want to know and also how to push to hub

Comment: Actually I just realized you are not actually using the hub. Check mobrockers answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it properly belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

To use selenium with the grid you need to start a **Remote** webdriver. What you're doing here is starting a local webdriver of types:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

This is not how you request a browser from the grid.
Furthermore, the path to the driver (`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");`) must be supplied to the **grid**, so you cannot set this in your code here.
You do this as follows:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role hub -Dwebdrivers.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe
```

What you are currently doing is creating local webdrivers, you are not connecting to the grid at all. Connecting to the grid is done as follows:

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(hub, dc);
```